# Is it possible to send commands between two MATLAB windows open on the same computer?

Tags: matlab

I want to have two MATLAB windows open on the same computer. The desired scenario is as follows: MATLAB window 1 is continuously running a script that has nothing to do with MATLAB window 2. At the same time, MATLAB window 2 is running a script that continuously checks for a certain condition, and if it is met, then it will terminate the script running on MATLAB window 1, and then terminate its own script as well. I want to have two MATLAB windows instead of one since I believe it will be more time efficient for what I am trying to do. I found an interesting "KeyInject" program at http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40001-keyinject , but I was wondering if there is a simpler way already built into MATLAB.

Comment: I can't see how this is at all efficient. If you can check for a condition in a live script in a separate MATLAB, why can't you just do it in the one instance?

Comment: To give some context here; I am actually using one MATLAB window to control a laser shooting a crystal, and another MATLAB window to analyze the images from a CCD to check if excessive crystal damage has occured due to the laser. If the crystal is damaged too much, then I want the laser to be shut off. For certain experimental reasons it is important to have the laser running continuously and the CCD controlled independently, hence the need for two MATLAB windows.

Comment: I do not see any reason why you should not be able to control your hardware from the same script - set your laser, read your sensor. This is standard in controller implementations. You create one main loop with an exit condition. The first step inside this loop is to read your sensor data and secondly to set the the input of your system... In your case, is there a reason why you are not able to do so?

Comment: I cannot do that because the laser must be running continuously (this takes very little computer resources), but the exit condition takes some time (maybe 1 second) to evaluate, which would interrupt the laser if it is included in the main loop. This is why I want a second MATLAB window to check the exit condition simultaneously to the laser running continuously.

Comment: I still don't understand why running an exit condition on a separate instance of MATLAB would mean that the laser isn't interrupted? You have to post your code otherwise we're just in the dark.

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the [parallel computing toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing.html)

Comment: Yes I did consider this, but I think the "KeyInject" I linked in my original post is more convenient for me. I will just use that I guess.

Comment: I agree with comments above, you should first think hard about your need to implement a decoupled control mechanism. But in case you really need to: You cannot share workspace or any variable between 2 independant instances of Matlab. One workaround would be to have the Matlab2 (M2) session create a file like `keep.going` (empty file is fine). The M1 session will continuously operate the laser and at the end of the loop check for the existence of the file. When M2 detect that the laser should be stopped, it delete the file, then M1 will detect that the file is gone then stop the laser.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want simple, or a flexible, infinitely expandable version 1.0? Simple would be to trigger System A via a file created by System B.

Simple would have System B create a file, then System A would check for the file with the command

```
    if exist ( fileName, 'file' )
```

then do your shutdown commands. On startup, System A would delete the file with

```
delete ( fileName );
```

The second option is to use the udp command. UDP allows any data to be sent between processes, whether on the same computer or over a network. (See https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/udp.html for more info).

Comment: Thanks, I think the file method is a very easy solution! I will use this.

Answer (score 1):

I see several ways:

1. Restructure to avoid this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
2. Use (mat) files (as Hoki suggested), possibly using the parallel computing toolbox to keep everything in one MATLAB session.
3. Write some MEX functions that communicate with each other via a [global pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx).
4. Write an [Auto(Hot)key](https://autohotkey.com/) script.

**Option 2** is probably easiest. Take a look at [events and listeners](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-concepts.html) if you write in OOP, otherwise, you'd have to poll inside a loop

**Option 3** is harder and *way* more time consuming to implement, but allows for much faster detection of the condition, and much faster data transfer between the sessions. Use only if speed is essential...but I guess that doesn't apply :)

**Option 4**: the AutoHotkey solution is probably the most Horrible Thing® you could do on an already Horrible Construction®, but oh what fun!! In both MATLAB sessions, you create a (hidden) figure with the name `Window1` or `Window2`, respectively. These window names are something that AutoHotkey can easily track. If the conditions are met, you update the corresponding window name, triggering the remainder of the AutoHotkey script: press a button in the other window! If you need to transfer data between the windows: you can create basic edit boxes in both GUIs, and copy-paste the data between them. If you're on Linux: you can use Autokey for the same purpose, but by then you're basically writing Python code doing the heavy lifting, so just use Python.

Or, you know, use KeyInject. Less fun.

Comment: ha ha ... I love your last solution, I'm trying to think of an even more convoluted way to achieve that but I think you topped it up ! +1 for the different (more sensible) choices at the beginning and the helping links.